# Linksys AC1200 not working in Gnome (Ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: networking, drivers, gnome, usb

Upgraded my wireless USB adapter to a Linksys AC1200 (WUSB6300).  I spent yesterday and today researching and trying to finally get it working and finally got it.

This is in an Ubuntu 18.04 environment.  I prefer Gnome so after getting the adapter working I installed Gnome, logged in and expected the new adapter to be fully functioning.  Not so.

The AC1200 (WUSB6300) shows up as an available Wi-Fi adapter in the GUI (Wi-Fi).  In the upper-right 'USB Wi-Fi Not Connected' is shown.  I hit 'Select Network' and it just sits and spins finding no networks.

If I relog, into Ubuntu, works just fine.

Still new to Linux so:

1. What could be causing the issue here, obviously something is going on with Gnome 3?
2. What commands would you advise me to run to get more pertinent information to help you solve this.

I couldn't find much searching forums and Google regarding this adapter and Gnome 3 --> Ubuntu 18.04 (plenty for 18.04 but nothing on Gnome).

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: How exactly did you solve it?

Comment: (1/2) I should have been more clear in my OP.  Obviously Ubuntu ships with Gnome 3.28 but I wanted to experiment with Vanilla Gnome and that's where I ran into the adapter issue described in the OP.

If you're asking how I finally got the Linksys AC1200 (WUSB6300) working under Ubuntu 18.04, I followed these steps:

1. sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r) build-essential git


2. git clone https://github.com/scrivy/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux


3. cd rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux


4. make


5.  sudo make install

sudo modprobe rtl8812au

Comment: (2/2)  Hope that helps anyone using 18.04 and this adapter.  Just found it strange that it works fine in Gnome 3.28 but not Gnome on Xorg.  Just a learning thing at this point, was hoping someone could point me to the mechanics of what was malfunctioning between the Gnome versions that would cause the adapter to sit and spin scanning for networks (never finding any) in 'Gnome on Xorg'.

Comment: Sorry, I know the formatting is off.  I haven't asked/commented here before (I don't think).  If I have it's been a long time.  I'll make it look more nice next time around.